# "Aesthetics must be either length" when filtering using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to filter my data based on some criteria before plotting in `ggplot2`.

When I plotted my entire dataset with the following command, everything worked as expected:

```
x_in %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x_in$`Turbine Wind Speed Adjusted m/s (m/s)`,
               y = x_in$`Turbine Power KW (kW)`)) +
    geom_point()
```

However, when I filtered the data before plotting it, I got an error:

```
x_in %>%
    dplyr::filter(`Turbine Wind Speed Adjusted m/s (m/s)`,
                  `Turbine Power KW (kW)` < 1700) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = x_in$`Turbine Wind Speed Adjusted m/s (m/s)`,
               y = x_in$`Turbine Power KW (kW)`)) +
    geom_point()

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (34812): x, y
```

Why do I get this error when I filter my data before plotting?

Here's the first 150 rows of my dataset using `dput`:

```
dput(x_in[1:150,])

structure(list(`Local Period (ending)` = c("1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 12:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 12:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 12:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 12:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 12:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 1:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 1:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 1:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 1:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 1:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 1:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 2:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 2:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 2:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 2:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 2:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 2:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 3:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 3:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 3:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 3:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 3:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 3:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 4:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 4:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 4:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 4:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 4:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 4:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 5:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 5:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 5:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 5:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 5:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 5:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 6:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 6:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 6:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 6:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 6:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 6:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 7:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 7:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 7:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 7:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 7:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 7:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 8:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 8:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 8:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 8:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 8:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 8:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 9:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 9:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 9:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 9:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 9:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 9:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 10:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 10:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 10:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 10:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 10:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 10:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 11:00:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 11:10:00 AM", "1/1/2018 11:20:00 AM", "1/1/2018 11:30:00 AM", 
"1/1/2018 11:40:00 AM", "1/1/2018 11:50:00 AM", "1/1/2018 12:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 12:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 12:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 12:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 12:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 12:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 1:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 1:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 1:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 1:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 1:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 1:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 2:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 2:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 2:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 2:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 2:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 2:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 3:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 3:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 3:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 3:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 3:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 3:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 4:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 4:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 4:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 4:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 4:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 4:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 5:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 5:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 5:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 5:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 5:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 5:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 6:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 6:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 6:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 6:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 6:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 6:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 7:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 7:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 7:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 7:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 7:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 7:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 8:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 8:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 8:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 8:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 8:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 8:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 9:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 9:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 9:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 9:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 9:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 9:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 10:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 10:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 10:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 10:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 10:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 10:50:00 PM", "1/1/2018 11:00:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 11:10:00 PM", "1/1/2018 11:20:00 PM", "1/1/2018 11:30:00 PM", 
"1/1/2018 11:40:00 PM", "1/1/2018 11:50:00 PM", "1/2/2018 12:00:00 AM", 
"1/2/2018 12:10:00 AM", "1/2/2018 12:20:00 AM", "1/2/2018 12:30:00 AM", 
"1/2/2018 12:40:00 AM", "1/2/2018 12:50:00 AM"), `Turbine Power KW (kW)` = c(1551.46, 
1552.08, 1552.7, 1553.33, 1553.95, 1554.57, 1555.19, 1555.81, 
1556.43, 1557.06, 1557.68, 1558.3, 1558.92, 1559.54, 1560.17, 
1560.79, 1561.41, 1562.03, 1562.65, 1563.28, 1563.9, 1564.52, 
1565.14, 1565.76, 1566.38, 1567.01, 1567.63, 1568.25, 1568.87, 
1569.49, 1570.12, 1570.74, 1571.36, 1571.98, 1572.6, 1573.23, 
1573.85, 1574.47, 1575.09, 1575.71, 1576.34, 1576.96, 1577.58, 
1578.2, 1578.82, 1579.44, 1580.07, 1580.69, 1581.31, 1581.93, 
1582.55, 1583.18, 1583.8, 1584.42, 1585.04, 1585.66, 1586.29, 
1586.91, 1587.53, 1588.15, 1588.77, 1589.4, 1590.02, 1590.64, 
1591.26, 1591.88, 1592.5, 1593.13, 1593.75, 1594.37, 1594.99, 
1595.61, 1596.24, 1596.86, 1597.48, 1598.1, 1598.72, 1599.35, 
1599.97, 1600.59, 1601.21, 1601.83, 1602.45, 1603.08, 1603.7, 
1604.32, 1604.94, 1605.56, 1606.19, 1606.81, 1607.43, 1608.05, 
1608.67, 1609.3, 1609.92, 1610.54, 1611.16, 1611.78, 1612.41, 
1613.03, 1613.65, 1614.27, 1614.89, 1615.51, 1616.14, 1616.76, 
1617.38, 1618, 1618.62, 1619.25, 1619.87, 1620.49, 1621.11, 1621.73, 
1622.36, 1622.98, 1623.6, 1624.22, 1624.84, 1625.46, 1626.09, 
1626.71, 1627.33, 1627.95, 1628.57, 1629.2, 1629.82, 1630.44, 
1631.06, 1631.68, 1632.31, 1632.93, 1633.55, 1634.17, 1634.79, 
1635.42, 1636.04, 1636.66, 1637.28, 1637.9, 1638.52, 1639.15, 
1639.77, 1640.39, 1641.01, 1641.63, 1642.26, 1642.88, 1643.5, 
1644.12), `Turbine Wind Speed Adjusted m/s (m/s)` = c(2.53, 2.53, 
2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 
8.76, 8.76, 8.77, 8.77, 8.77, 8.77, 8.77, 8.78, 8.78, 8.78, 8.78, 
8.79, 8.79, 8.79, 8.79, 8.79, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.81, 8.81, 
8.81, 8.81, 8.81, 8.82, 8.82, 8.82, 8.82, 8.83, 8.83, 8.83, 8.83, 
8.83, 8.84, 8.84, 8.84, 8.84, 8.85, 8.85, 8.85, 8.85, 8.86, 8.86, 
8.86, 8.86, 8.86, 8.87, 8.87, 8.87, 8.87, 8.88, 8.88, 8.88, 8.88, 
8.88, 8.89, 8.89, 8.89, 8.89, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.91, 
8.91, 8.91, 8.91, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.92, 8.93, 8.93, 8.93, 
8.93, 8.94, 8.94, 8.94, 8.94, 8.94, 8.95, 8.95, 8.95, 8.95, 8.96, 
8.96, 8.96, 8.96, 8.97, 8.97, 8.97, 8.97, 8.97, 8.98, 8.98, 8.98, 
8.98, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 8.99, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9.01, 9.01, 9.01, 
9.01, 9.01, 9.02, 9.02, 9.02, 9.02, 9.03, 9.03, 9.03, 9.03, 9.03, 
9.04, 9.04, 9.04, 9.04, 9.05, 9.05, 9.05, 9.05, 9.05, 9.06, 9.06, 
9.06, 9.06, 9.07), `Turbine Expected Power KW (kW)` = c(26.24, 
26.24, 26.24, 26.24, 26.24, 26.24, 26.24, 26.24, 26.24, 26.24, 
26.24, 26.24, 26.24, 1674.48, 1674.48, 1674.48, 1674.48, 1674.48, 
1674.72, 1674.72, 1674.72, 1674.72, 1674.96, 1674.96, 1674.96, 
1674.96, 1675.2, 1675.2, 1675.2, 1675.2, 1675.2, 1675.44, 1675.44, 
1675.44, 1675.44, 1675.68, 1675.68, 1675.68, 1675.68, 1675.68, 
1675.92, 1675.92, 1675.92, 1675.92, 1676.16, 1676.16, 1676.16, 
1676.16, 1676.16, 1676.4, 1676.4, 1676.4, 1676.4, 1676.64, 1676.64, 
1676.64, 1676.64, 1676.64, 1676.88, 1676.88, 1676.88, 1676.88, 
1677.12, 1677.12, 1677.12, 1677.12, 1677.12, 1677.36, 1677.36, 
1677.36, 1677.36, 1677.6, 1677.6, 1677.6, 1677.6, 1677.6, 1677.84, 
1677.84, 1677.84, 1677.84, 1678.08, 1678.08, 1678.08, 1678.08, 
1678.32, 1678.32, 1678.32, 1678.32, 1678.32, 1678.56, 1678.56, 
1678.56, 1678.56, 1678.8, 1678.8, 1678.8, 1678.8, 1678.8, 1679.04, 
1679.04, 1679.04, 1679.04, 1679.28, 1679.28, 1679.28, 1679.28, 
1679.28, 1679.52, 1679.52, 1679.52, 1679.52, 1679.76, 1679.76, 
1679.76, 1679.76, 1679.76, 1680, 1680, 1680, 1680, 1680.24, 1680.24, 
1680.24, 1680.24, 1680.24, 1680.48, 1680.48, 1680.48, 1680.48, 
1680.72, 1680.72, 1680.72, 1680.72, 1680.96, 1680.96, 1680.96, 
1680.96, 1680.96, 1681.2, 1681.2, 1681.2, 1681.2, 1681.44, 1681.44, 
1681.44, 1681.44, 1681.44, 1681.68, 1681.68, 1681.68)), row.names = c(NA, 
150L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share the data using `dput(x_in)`?

Comment: Your life will be much happier if you use column names with no spaces or special characters. Long, complicated column names like you have will be both awkward and a source of difficulties. Second, when specifying aesthetics in `aes()`, you should never, ever, use `$`, as in `data$column`. The point of `aes()` is that you only type the column name: `aes(x = column)`. Of course, that will be easier once you've fixed your column names! ;)

Comment: Dput added. Also @joran, I have no control over the column names unfortunately (unless I change them). I hate it. But removing the $ seemed to be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, my point was that when working with data in R, it is best to modify the column names yourself, if necessary, into something that is more feasible. Otherwise, you're just asking for pain. Trust me, you're not going to want to keep working with column names that long and convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're supposed to work with `ggplot` is to pass a dataset into the `data=` argument, and then use the `aes` function to define the mapping between variables in the dataset and in the plot. For example, if you wanted to plot the `cars` dataset, you might do this:

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
    geom_point()
```

Since you provided a blank name to `aes`, ggplot knows that `speed` refers to a variable in the `cars` object, essentially `cars$speed`, not an independent object in the environment. If you wanted to, though, you could override this by passing an object to `aes`:

```
cars2 <- cars * 2
ggplot(cars, aes(x = cars2$speed, y = dist)) +
    geom_point()
```

Now, you'll see that you're now plotting `cars$dist` vs `cars2$speed`.

So, what does this have to do with you? When you pipe an object into `ggplot` with the pipe operator `%>%` it puts that object in the `data=` argument. So:

```
cars %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
    geom_point()
```

In your example, you take `x_in`, pipe it into `filter` and than pipe the output into the `data=` argument of `ggplot`. Note that the pipe **DOES NOT** edit the value of `x_in`, it just passes the output down the pipe. So the saved object  `x_in` doesn't change. The only place the filtered version of `x_in` is going in your example is into `ggplot(data=`

But when you set up your `aes`, instead of passing bare names (which would tell `ggplot` to look for those variables in the data frame you passed into `data=`) you specify a specific object:

```
aes(x = x_in$`Turbine Wind Speed Adjusted m/s (m/s)` ...
```

Because you specified `x_in$`, ggplot will use the `` `Turbine Wind Speed ... ` `` variable in the `x_in` object in the environment which has not been filtered and, therefore, has a different number of rows than the data that `ggplot` expects to be working with.

To solve this, simply remove the `x_in$` from your `aes` so that ggplot will correctly use the data you piped in.

Comment: I feel like a clown, this fixed it. Much appreciated for the explanation.

Comment: @Nick Glad I could help!